# How to change cycle jquery caption text fadein, fadeout to bounce effect?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-cycle

I am using cycle jquery as a slideshow for my site.
This is my html code.

```
 <div class="slideshow_item">
    <div class="image"><a href="#"><img src="#"/></a></div>
    <div class="data">
    <h4><a href="#">title1</h4>
    <p>content</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The below one is my javascript code

```
<script>
$(function() {

// ---------------------------------------------------
// Slideshow 1

    $('#slideshow_1').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',       
        easing: 'easeInOutCirc',
        speed:  700,    
        timeout: 5000, 
        pager: '.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_paging', 
        prev: '.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_prev',
        next: '.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_next',
        before: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement) {
            var data = $('.data', $(nextSlideElement)).html();
            $('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box .data').fadeOut(1200, function(){
                $('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box .data').remove();
                $('<div class="data">'+data+'</div>').hide().appendTo('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box').fadeIn(1200);
            });
        }
    });

    // not using the 'pause' option. instead make the slideshow pause when the mouse is over the whole wrapper
    $('.ss1_wrapper').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#slideshow_1').cycle('pause');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('#slideshow_1').cycle('resume');
    });

// ---------------------------------------------------

    $('a[href="#"]').click(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault(); // for this demo disable all links that point to "#"
    });

});
</script>
```

In the html code under .data i have h4 and p tags. 
The slider works great with slide horizontal and the caption (.data) which flows on the slider because of position absolute in .data and it works fine. 
Now, my question is, how to bounce my caption(.data) from top to bottom, or left side to right side animatically by changing the above javascript incase of fadein and fadeout.
Please help me.

Comment: This would be much easier to troubleshoot if you had a jsFiddle.

Comment: how to do it? how do i have jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Bounce effect comes with jquery ui, so don't forget to include this library on your page. 
I guess you may call effect() method to achieve the result you want.
It's possible to set 4 options to "bounce" effect:

**Direction**: The direction of the effect. Can be "up", "down", "left", "right". Default is "up".
**Distance**: Distance to bounce. Default is 20 
**Mode**: The mode of the effect. Can be "show", "hide" or "effect". Default is "effect". 
**Times**: Times to bounce. Default is 5.

It's up to you what direction, distance and times to choose, but here the most important for us is mode. Instead of fadeOut, which hides element, we will set mode to 'hide' and instead of fadeIn, which shows element, we will set mode to 'show'.

Here is how method looks like:

```
.effect("bounce", {mode: "hide", times: 4, direction: "up"}, 1200, function(){});
```

As you see, first of all, we chose "bounce" effect, then goes an array with some of the available options, then goes duration (in your case its 1200 or 1.2 second) and the last one is a function which runs after effect ends.

Here is quick jFiddle example how bounce works with 'show' and 'hide' mode: http://jsfiddle.net/Z73P5/2/

So, try to change your 'before' parameter of cycle plugin with this. Hope it will work.

```
before: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement) {

        var data = $('.data', $(nextSlideElement)).html();

        $('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box .data').effect("bounce", {times: 4, direction: "up", mode: "hide"}, 1200, function(){
            $('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box .data').remove();
            $('<div class="data">'+data+'</div>').hide().appendTo('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box').effect("bounce", {times: 4, direction: "down", mode: "show"}, 1200);
        });

    }
```